# RAP Application Load Testing with JMeter does not work, why?

Tags: jmeter, eclipse-rap

I tried to "load testing" my simple rap workbench application, which deployed on local server, but this does not work. I get error code 403, session timeout. I followed to this steps on [Eclipse Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/LoadTesting), but it is not works in my case.

Here are some snapshots, to understand what my problem is:

[image: My JMeter Settings]

Here is my HTTP Request

[HTTP Request Recorded by JMeter](https://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/LoadTesting) (RAP/LoadTesting)

Comment: Can you show your HTTP request settings?

Comment: Can you copy the same request that JMeter is sending  and send from browser? @vaadin